# Auto Form Fill for Windows Application

Tags: c#, windows, forms, autofill

Detecting text fields are a common job in Form Fillers for browsers.
Is there a way to detect text fields and labels in an windows application using C++ or C#?
I want to write an Auto Form Filler for windows applications.

Answer (score 2):

Taking abmv's answer further, there are several tools for this, some for .NET, too:

- [Windows Forms Spy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wfspy.aspx)
- [.NET Control Inspector](http://oaklandsoftware.com/product_compinsp1/product_1.html)
- [ManagedSpy in MSDN Magazine of April 2006](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx)
- [Hawkeye](http://www.acorns.com.au/Projects/Hawkeye/)

Spy++ itself can be [found on Microsoft's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), the source code seems to be not available, but a [similar tool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/windowfinder.aspx) has source code.

Comment: Spy++ is not an open source one! I want to do It myself, read the question again please.

Comment: Just look at the very last hyperlink in my answer. And BTW, where did you mention Open Source in your question?

Comment: "Is there a way to detect text fields and labels in an windows application using C++ or C#? I want to write an Auto Form Filler for windows applications." it means I need code to write an application not tools.

Comment: Dude, there are form filler applications already in the market.Why do you want to reinvent the wheel(check any enterprise sso solution).Plus you need write it in c++ not c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try a tool like SPY++ you can see that it can detect lables